# how to create If Statement with push notification?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to create an If statement with the data of my push notification.
The if statement should go something like this :
" if 3 words of the push notification text is equal to the cell title, then change the colour of the cell ".
this is the code in my appDelegate  that handle the push

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    // The application was just brought from the background to the foreground,
    // so we consider the app as having been "opened by a push notification."

    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
       }}
```

now i'm supposed to put my If statement, but I don't know how the logic goes.
As I mentioned, I'm trying to write something like:
" if three words of the push notification are equal to the table view cell results, then ..."
thank you for any help .

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. so far I thought about Regex, I would love to get a pattern of code since it's kind of complicated to create such a code.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have so far. As it is right now, it's hard to tell exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I Edit my question, I'm sorry but I read the Parse docs and there is nothing about how to handle this push notification text.

Comment: edit: oh, getting the push text... hm. Ok, so you understand what's possible, but you need to know how to parse the string? That's not so hard, maybe you should look for string questions instead of Notification ones, since your question is about the string. There are many ways, esp for NSString

Comment: Can you please show me one way. I searched here, and in Parse Docs but couldn't find info about it. I just want to save the push notification text as string, how can I do it  ?